# Does the dot(.) have a special name in database?

Tags: sql

It is just a simple question, when we want to see fields in the table, we write the table name and the tool (Toad for oracle, pl/sql developer etc.) lists all fields that table has. Does dot have a special name? One of my friends insists on this and he does not say the name of it.

```
select * from customer.
                      ^
```

Comment: It is often referred to as the "dot operator" or "dot notation".

Comment: It is a syntax element (*scope separator*) : `schemaname.tablename.columnname` or similarly: `aliasname.columnname`

Comment: It's called the schema (or catalog) _separator_ (there are actually DBMS that use a different character for that)

Comment: "period" it also called as period

Comment: In at least [one place](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements009.htm) Oracle calls them "periods separating the components of the reference to the object"; but that just seems to be the generic ['period'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/period) name. Not sure if you're asking specifically about in a DBMS context or just for other names for the dot generally.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you have an example for a DBMS which do use another character as scope separator?

Comment: @emfi: some versions of DB2  use a different character

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks!